# what is wrong with this code? can only concatenate str

Tags: python

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, givenname, personality, is_sitting):
        self.name = givenname
        self.personality = personality
        self.is_sitting = is_sitting
    
    def sit_down(self):
        self.is_sitting = True
    def stand_up(self):
        self.is_sitting = False
    def intro_self(self):
        print("My name is " + self.name)
        print("I am " + self.personality)
        print("I am" + self.is_sitting)
        print()
p1 = Person("Moaz", "aggeressive", True)
p2 = Person("kamal", "aggeressive", False)
```

I wrote this code regarding classes and objects in python. I am new in Python.
Tell me what is wrong in it. The issue is probably with 4th last line.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11082165). Could you elaborate on what the expected and actual behavior of your code is?

Comment: What's wrong with it? You tell us. Then maybe we can explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is:

*line 16, in intro_self
print("I am" + self.is_sitting)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bool") to str*

That means, python does not know how to 'glue' a string ("I am") and a bool (self.is_sitting) together.
A `bool` can be `true` or `false`, but it makes no sense to use this directly in your response. What should it be? "I am true" or "I am false"? That makes no sense.
So you should print a different text for your different cases:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, givenname, personality, is_sitting):
        self.name = givenname
        self.personality = personality
        self.is_sitting = is_sitting

    def sit_down(self):
        self.is_sitting = True

    def stand_up(self):
        self.is_sitting = False

    def intro_self(self):
        print("My name is" + self.name)
        print("I am " + self.personality)
        if self.is_sitting:
            print("I am sitting")
        else:
            print("I am not sitting")
```

As a general advice: In the beginning the error messages can be a bit confusing due to all that stuff they say, but it's worth reading them. They give you a hint where in your code something fails and especially `what` produced the error.

Answer (score 0):

when I run `intro_self` I got `can only concatenate str (not "bool") to str`.
I assumed it's the error you encounter.

There are multiple ways to solve this :

```
print(f"I am {self.is_sitting}")
```

or

```
print("I am {0}".format(self.is_sitting))
```

or

```
print("I am " + str(self.is_sitting))
```

I advise you to use "f strings" witch is the first solution, you can read more here: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/